# When scroll the list Images are showing repeatly or double

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview

> Here is class which i load the images locally from drawable i want to shows the actual images not double images in list.

```
 public class ActivityIntroduction extends Activity {

ListView list;

Integer[] imgid={
        R.drawable.introduction_1,R.drawable.introduction_2,R.drawable.introduction_3,

};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    //  findViewById(R.id.title1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.duwaine_head);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_back1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ActivityIntroduction.this.finish();

        }
    });
    AdapterListextends adapter=new AdapterListextends(this, imgid);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
 }
```

**Here is Adapter but when i scroll the list speedily then the images shows double or repeatly**

```
class AdapterListextends extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
LayoutInflater vi;

private final Activity context;
private final Integer[] imgid;
ViewHolder holder;
public AdapterListextends(Activity context, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_view, imgid);

    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    this.context = context;
    this.imgid = imgid;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected static ImageView imageview;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_view, null);

        holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        v.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageview.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    return v;

}


  }
```

Comment: make you holder `ViewHolder holder` from outside to the `getView` function inside

Comment: Issue not resolved please give me another solution..

Comment: Please help me and suggest me another solution..

Comment: Make the int position final - getview(final int position...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change ViewHolder imageview acess from  protected static to private

```
static class ViewHolder {
   private ImageView imageview;
}
```

it should work

Answer (score 1):

**Olny change the Holder static to final**

Answer (score 0):

**Yes but i make this View Holder and it work fine for me**

```
class AdapterListextends extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
LayoutInflater vi;

private final Activity context;
private final Integer[] imgid;
public AdapterListextends(Activity context, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_view, imgid);

    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    this.context = context;
    this.imgid = imgid;
}

final class ViewHolder {
     ImageView imageview;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_view, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.imageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        // viewHolder.type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Type);

    } else {
        view = convertView;

    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.imageview.setImageResource(imgid[position]);


    return view;
}


     }
```